# how to grep a list of patterns from a file & ignore the same from another file?

Tags: grep, ksh

this is what i'm trying >>

grep 'pattern' FILE1 | grep 'ignore_pattern' from FILE2

I was doing this for individual patterns >> 
grep 'errmsg' log_file | grep -v '88909'

but i have more than one pattern to ignore, so I have them as a list in a file FILE2.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The word "pattern" is highly ambiguous and should be avoided. Replace it with "string" or "regexp" as appropriate in your question. Make sure when you add your missing sample input/output to include the rainy day cases of similar and/or partial strings you do not want to match.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep pattern file1 | grep -vf file2
```